# Sequential processing of a variable number of async functions in Dart

Tags: dart, future

I need to repeatedly call an asynchronous function in Dart, let's call it `expensiveFunction`, for a variable number of arguments. However, since each call is quite memory consuming, I cannot afford to run them in parallel. How do I force them to run in sequence?

I have tried this:

```
argList.forEach( await (int arg) async {
  Completer c = new Completer();
  expensiveFunction(arg).then( (result) {
    // do something with the result
    c.complete();
  });
  return c.future;
});
```

but it hasn't had the intended effect. The `expensiveFunction` is still being called in parallel for each `arg` in `argList`. What I actually need is to wait in the `forEach` loop until the `expensiveFunction` completes and only then to proceed with the next element in the `argList`. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll want to use a classic `for` loop here:

```
doThings() async {
  for (var arg in argList) {
    await expensiveFunction(arg).then((result) => ...);
  }
}
```

There are some nice examples [on the language tour](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/language/await-async#putting-it-all-together).

Comment: So simple... Why didn't I think of it? I managed to solve it through recursion, but your solution is much more elegant.

Comment: You can also use `Future.forEach(argList, expensiveFunction)`.